# JMeter Aggressivity

Tags: http, iis, jmeter, stress-testing

I am trying to stress test a IIS running a AspNet core App.
to do this i setup a Thread Group with 100 workers
In the thread group I use a Loop Controller
in the loop controller I use a Access Log sampler in order to replay real Get requests obtained from NCSA formatted logfile.

I am amazed to see that i obtain as total throughput only 100 request per sec.
how can i check if this is a limitation of jmeter or if this is a limitation of my web App ?
I would expect jmeter to blast my server and see target CPU shoot at 100%. or shall I increas again already high value of 100 threads ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Total throughput is 86 requests per second
2. 100 users might be not enough to "blast" your IIS instance, I would rather recommend going for [stress test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Stress_testing), i.e. start with 1 user and gradually increase the load until throughput starts decreasing or errors start occurring, whatever comes the first. Moreover it might be the case that the [bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing) is not CPU usage, it may be somewhere else, in case of incorrect configuration or inefficient algorithms the web application may not fully utilize underlying OS and hardware resources
3. Don't use GUI mode for testing, it's only for test development and debugging, when it comes to execution [you should be running JMeter tests in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode)
4. There are 464 errors, check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries
5. I don't think you can really replay your access log, it can be used only for something simple like static HTML pages, if there is authentication or dynamic parameters it might be the case all your requests are hitting the same login page, you can try running your test using [View Results Tree listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) and inspect the responses to ensure that your test is doing what it's supposed to be doing

[image]